# Working with RS232 and USB

Tags: usb, serial

I have a device that only has a RS232 serial port for communication. Since board cases would be used, RS232 serial interface is not preferred. Instead, I would like to use a RS232 to USB converter.

Regarding this implementation, I would like to know if there is any converter that could be used for Raspberry Pi 2. My main concern is whether its driver can be used on Ubuntu MATE for Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: See also: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usb-serial.txt ...But if you want an opinion, opting for USB <-> RS232 because "cases would be used" seems daft.  The adapters are going to cost a sizable proportion of the whole board cost, plus you have this added hassle, when you could just as easily run a harness through the case.

Comment: @goldilocks: Perhaps...  But USB to serial adapters are often ~$10.  And perhaps he doesn't want to drill through the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just as a point of reference, I have a SIIG serial adapter (based on FTDI's FT232BM chip) that works fine.

Check out:

> http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_UART_and_USB_to_Serial_.28RS-232.29_adapters